# Get heart rate sensor data on Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os, android-sensors, android-wear-2.0, moto-360

I am trying to get the heart rate sensor data on my Android Wear device (`Moto 360`). But I don't know why the `TYPE_HEART_RATE` is not recognized, and the app says `sensor registered: no`. Other types like `STEP_COUNTER` returns `yes`.

What is the problem?!

```
public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // register us as a sensor listener
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        Sensor mHeartRateSensor = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_HEART_RATE);
        boolean res = mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mHeartRateSensor,  SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, " sensor registered: " + (res ? "yes" : "no"));

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(Wearable.API).build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We should go to the smartwatch's `Settings-->Apps-->[App Name]-->Permissions` in order to check if that permission is enabled. It's disabled by default!